# boto3 read bucket files using concurrency method

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, concurrency, boto3

I am trying to read bucket files without to saving them as a file:

```
    import boto3
    import botocore
    from io import StringIO
    import pandas as pd
    
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3',config=botocore.config.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED))
    bucket = self.s3.Bucket('deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds')
    objects = self.bucket.objects.filter(Prefix= date)
    file = pd.read_csv(StringIO(self.bucket.Object(key=object.key).get().get('Body').read().decode('utf-8')))
```

This code works quite well. However, I would like to use concurrency (python asyncio) to speed up the reading process. I did a search into documentation but I could only find something for the download function but not for the get function.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: asyncio does not speed up code, it lets you do other things while waiting for background tasks.  It seems a bit pointless in the case of a lambda and waiting for the download to use asyncio.

Comment: What if a try to read each csv in concurrency?

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution which works with multiprocessing since my final goal was to reduce the processing time.

As follow the code:

```
def generate_bucket():
        s3_resoursce = boto3.resource('s3',config=botocore.config.Config(signature_version=botocore.UNSIGNED))
        xetra_bucket = s3_resoursce.Bucket('deutsche-boerse-xetra-pds')
        
        return s3_resoursce, xetra_bucket

def read_csv(object):
    s3local, bucket_local = self.generate_bucket()

    return pd.read_csv(StringIO(bucket_local.Object(key=object).get().get('Body').read().decode('utf-8')))


def import_raw_data(date: List[str]) -> pd.DataFrame:
        import multiprocessing
        
        s3local, bucket_local2 = self.generate_bucket()   
        objects = [i.key for i in list(bucket_local2.objects.filter(Prefix= date[0]))]
        
        with multiprocessing.Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()) as p:
            df = pd.concat(p.map(self.read_csv, objects))
        
    return df
```

For me it works, but I am sure that there could be the possibility to improve this code. I'm open to suggestions.